# where to change the project configuration into the updated build tool revision in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android studio project, I have pre-installed Build Tools 24.3.2 and 22, however a sample project I am going to run requires Build Tools revision 21.1.2

```
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2
```

I wonder could I not install the Build Tools revision 21.1.2 and just change the project configuration to fit into 24.3.2 or 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the updated **Build tools**. And it will not create any problem to build your gradle project.

Just modify the `build.gradle` from the app module with the **latest build tool version**:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "24.3.3" //most update version I can see in my sdk manager

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.support.android.designlibdemo"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

**Note:** Just for making life easier some developers feels better to share what version of build tool they used while they smoothly deployed the project. So that it will be easier to report any bugs in more specific way.